# Broadcom BCM5720 Debian Bookworm

Tags: linux, debian, broadcom, lenovo, debian-bookworm

I have a problem on a Lenovo SR650 server. I installed Debian 12, with kernel 6.1.0-15 and all firmware packages for the Broadcom BCM5720 network interface. The interfaces are recognized but there is no link with the switch. Even forcing with ethtool, they do not close the physical link with the switch. The connected network cable is CAT6 Furukawa. A few years ago I had a similar problem with a Dell R730 server, I remember having to load the modules manually when installing Debian. However, this time it is already recognized by the kernel, but the link does not go up. Has anyone experienced this and knows how to resolve it?